# Views in page callback function

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

In my module I have a page callback function. I want 2 views on this page. How can I do this?

```
function MY_MODULE_menu() {
  $items['page-with-views/%'] = array
  (
    'title' => 'Page with vviews',
    'page callback' => 'MY_MODULE_page_callback',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function MY_MODULE_page_callback() {
  //views_embed_view('view_name','block'); ???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer: https://drupal.org/node/1370230
lalalalala